# How to return an async arrow function?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, arrow-functions, dispatch-async

I'm using React with Redux and have the following code:

`hooks.js`:

```
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { checkCookieOne, checkCookieTwo } from './thunk';
...
export function useValidateCookieEffect() {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    React.useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(checkCookieOne());
        dispatch(checkCookieTwo());
    }, [dispatch]);
}
```

And in my `thunk` file:

```
export function checkCookieOne() {
    return async dispatch => {
        const hasCookie = Boolean(window.localStorage.getItem('cookieOne') || false);
        dispatch(store.actions.toggleCookieOneValue(hasCookie));
    };
}

export function checkCookieTwo() {
    return async dispatch => {
        const hasCookie = Boolean(window.localStorage.getItem('cookieTwo') || false);
        dispatch(store.actions.toggleCookieTwoValue(hasCookie));
    };
}
```

And to make it a bit more readable, I wanted to consolidate the code into single line returns.

So, from:

```
export function checkCookieOne() {
    return async dispatch => {
        const hasCookie = Boolean(window.localStorage.getItem('cookieOne') || false);
        dispatch(store.actions.toggleCookieOneValue(hasCookie));
    };
}
```

to something like this (my attempt) - bearing in mind that `dispatch` isn't declared in this file, it's only declared in `hooks.js`:

```
export async function checkCookieOne() => dispatch(store.actions.toggleCookieOneValue(checkGivenCookieExists('cookieOne')));
```

But that's invalid syntax. It complains about the arrow function, saying:

> '{' or ';' expected.

How can I make this into a one line return?

```
export function checkCookieOne() { return async dispatch => dispatch(store.actions.toggleCookieOneValue(checkGivenCookieExists('cookieOne'))); }
```

This works but it's not exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
let checkCookieOne = async () => dispatch(store.actions.toggleMyCookieValue(checkGivenCookieExists('cookieOne')));

export checkCookieOne;

// Or maybe...

export let checkCookieOne = async () => dispatch(store.actions.toggleMyCookieValue(checkGivenCookieExists('cookieOne')));
```